# Order of output fields of each document from SOLR server

Tags: solr, solrj

I am currently running a large-ish metadata faceted browser.
I would like to influence the order of the fields of each document as the document is output from the server.
This differs and does not correlate with the order the fields are defined in the solr config, nor with the order the fields are populated in the solr config.

As a concrete example, there is one field that links directly to the original file before ingestion. I would like to have this field always show up at the bottom of the document.
(if it was only this than I would just hack it, however the relative ordering of the fields within the same document matters for all kinds of things, e.g., language code and language name should be next to eachother, etc.)

Does anyone have a way of making solr order the fields in a document?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ordering fields with [fl parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl)?

Comment: No I have not. However it sounds like a very worthwhile suggestion, I will be on it forthwith.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work.  The fields always come back in ASCII sort order (uppercase A-Z then lowercase A-Z).

Answer (score 0):

if you still have this issue, i think the only way to achieve this is to write a solr-plugin which does this for you.

You'll need to build your own result-list with the field-order you need.

You can Extend the Solr-Query-Component and do this job after calling super() in the process method.

Here you have to load the results for each document in the result-list from the index via SolrIndexSearcher (rb.req.getSearcher()) and order the fields as you need.

greetings René